# Why could select 1 from dual be itermittently slow on the database side?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, latency

Servers: Weblogic 12.1.1 (being upgraded soon, yes); Database: Oracle 12c

Our (very old) JSP monitoring page does `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` to check for the database being up and a very basic check on response time. We also have (newer) AppDynamics monitoring on our servers, which includes monitoring the monitoring page.

Lately we have been experiencing overall application slowness, and the monitoring page has been reflecting that. In particular `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL` query which we expect to be very consistent has been intermittently slow...as in 2+ seconds just for that query as reported by AppDynamics, when a normal response time is 50ms.

Mostly our focus has been on the network because that seems the most likely, but we haven't found anything.

What conditions on the database side could cause this? The database is run by a separate team, and they're helpful but they're responsible for a large number of applications, so we get the best effect if we can ask for specific, measurable statistics.

Comment: you could take a look at v$sql in the database to find out if the time is actually spend in the database

Comment: You could also try v$active_session_history, assuming you are licenced for the tuning pack. I would be very, very surprised if the issue was the query, though; far more likely to be the network, the OS (either of the database server or wherever your jsp code is running) or something to do with the interfaces (maybe ODBC or whatever you're using to connect to the db in your code).